# Label not Showing Variable as Coded

Tags: vb.net, label

I have a series of tests which when completed by a user the score is stored in a variable and written into a file. Within my program is a progress screen for each user, which is supposed to show all of the test scores in labels.

I have used this code to show the score in the label :
 lblTopic1Score.Text = Topic1Score

However when I run the system and go onto the progress form the label is blank.
Can anyone help ?

Code for the Progress form:

```
 Private Sub StProgress_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblTopic1Score.Text = Topic1Score
        lblTotalScore.Text = TotalScore

        lblStName.Text = namest
        LblStSurname.Text = surnamest

End Sub
```

Module was created to store Public variables
`Public Topic1Score As String`

This is a code extract from the test itself

`If answers(i) = questions(i, 4) And FileOpenStatusTS = False Then`

```
            Topic1Score += 1
            TotalScore += 1

        End If

    Next

    If yearst = "12" And classst = "A" Then
        FileOpen(1, FileName12A1, OpenMode.Append)
        FileOpenStatus12A1 = True

        'Once all the details have been entered and checked, then they are written to the Teacher accounts text file'
        WriteLine(1, Username, Topic1Score, TotalScore)
        FileClose(1)
    End If`
```

Comment: We need more than that to go on, in order to help you. Can you post some code?

Comment: Which part of the code do you need ?

Comment: A [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) would be great. Reduce *everything* until the program cannot be reduced further (while still demonstrating the problem), then post the (remaining) code, which should be no longer than a few lines.

Comment: Variables are populated with something? place a breakpoint then chek the variables.

Comment: I have re-edited with extracts from the code that involve Topic1Score

Comment: Is the label really blank or can you just not see it? A lot of time labels get hidden due to poor placement. Try changing its background color to something noticeable and see if you can at least see it. Maybe you just need to bring it to the foreground with .bringToFront(). If you are sure you can see it, then place a hard coded value in it until your code changes it. See if your code actually does change the value and what does it change it to. And so on until you find your answer.

Comment: I have solved this now, but thanks anyways I had already tried that.